# Confidence interval for partial correlations

Tags: r, correlation, confidence-interval

`cor.test` gives the 95 percent confidence interval for a correlation, however if we want to assess a partial correlation, `pcor.test` does not appear to give this information. could anyone advise on a way to find this in R?

Answer (score 0):

To find the confidence interval for the partial correlation, use the definition of partial correlation ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation#Formal_definition)) and run `cor.test`.

If the variables are `x`, `y` and `z` (the latter could be a matrix or data.frame), the following code could be run.

```
fit1 <- lm(x ~ z, data = xyz)
fit2 <- lm(y ~ z, data = xyz)
ci <- cor.test(resid(fit1), resid(fit2), 
               method = method, 
               conf.level = conf.level, ...)$conf.int
```

Since R is open source, the code of [`ppcor::pcor.test`](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/ppcor/html/pcor.test.html) is available and a function can be written combining it with the above way. Credits to the author must be given, see section `Author(s)` in its help page,

> Author(s)
> Seongho Kim biostatistician.kim@gmail.com

See also

```
maintainer("ppcor")
#[1] "Seongho Kim <biostatistician.kim@gmail.com>"
```

An example such function is below.

```
pcor_ci.test <-
function (x, y, z, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"), conf.level = 0.95, ...) {
    d1 <- deparse(substitute(x))
    d2 <- deparse(substitute(y))
    d3 <- deparse(substitute(z))
    data.name <- paste0(d1, " and ", d2, "; controlling: ", d3)
    method <- match.arg(method)
    Method <- paste0("Partial correlation (", method, ")")
    alternative <- "true partial correlation is not equal to 0"

    x <- as.vector(x)
    y <- as.vector(y)
    z <- as.data.frame(z)
    xyz <- data.frame(x, y, z)
    pcor <- ppcor::pcor(xyz, method = method)
    estimate <- pcor$est[1, 2]
    p.value <- pcor$p.value[1, 2]
    parameter <- c(n = pcor$n, gp = pcor$gp)
    statistic <- c(Stat = pcor$statistic[1, 2])

    fit1 <- lm(x ~ z, data = xyz)
    fit2 <- lm(y ~ z, data = xyz)
    cortest <- cor.test(resid(fit1), resid(fit2), method = method, conf.level = conf.level, ...)
    ci <- cortest$conf.int

    ht <- list(
        statistic = statistic,
        parameter = parameter,
        p.value = p.value,
        estimate = c(partial.cor = estimate),
        alternative = alternative,
        method = Method,
        data.name = data.name,
        conf.int = ci
    )
    class(ht) <- "htest"
    ht
}
```

Sample run, output omited:

```
set.seed(2020)

x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
z <- rnorm(10)

pcor_ci.test(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting `ht$estimate` different from `cortest$estimate`  -- any idea why? I have effect modifiers in `z` as explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589561).

Comment: @jessexknight I cannot reproduce the difference, can you post an example that does?